# window-based react hook makes sidebar flicker

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using this react hook in a next.js app.

It is supposed to return the width and the state of my sidebar

```
export const useSidebarWidth = () => {
  const [sidebarWidth, setSidebarWidth] = useState(SIDEBAR_WIDTH);
  const handleResize = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth < SIDEBAR_BREAKPOINT) {
      setSidebarWidth(SIDEBAR_WIDTH);
    } else {
      setSidebarWidth(SIDEBAR_WIDTH_EXPANDED);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    handleResize();
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  const isExpanded = useMemo(() => {
    return sidebarWidth === SIDEBAR_WIDTH_EXPANDED;
  }, [sidebarWidth]);

  return {
    sidebarWidth: isExpanded ? SIDEBAR_WIDTH_EXPANDED : SIDEBAR_WIDTH,
    isExpanded,
  };
};
```

Unfortunately, when navigating through my app, the sidebar flickers: for a short moment, it takes its small width, and immediately after, it expands. This happens every time I move to another page.

How can I make sure that this doesn't happen ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your build configuration, *window.innerwidth* may be initially set to 0 for the first frame and then be updated next render. For example, I tried re-creating this issue and got the same result in a CRA application but not in a Vite application.

Either way, one possible solution is to use *window.outerWidth*, which is usually the same as *window.innerWidth* for most end-users. A possible implementation in your case would be:

```
    const width = window.innerWidth === 0 ? window.outerWidth : window.innerWidth;
    if (width < SIDEBAR_BREAKPOINT) {
      setSidebarWidth(SIDEBAR_WIDTH);
    } else {
      setSidebarWidth(SIDEBAR_WIDTH_EXPANDED);
    }
```

This is obviously not a perfect solution, but I think it's better than what you have, as *window.outerWidth* is a more accurate estimate of *window.innerWidth* than 0 is.